# Find maximum index of an array nested in a hash in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash with two keys and the values are in an array. so,

```
%graph;
@{$graph{$root}{"children"} = ('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
```

I am trying to get the maximal size of the index which is 2, usually I would do

```
$#array
```

However, when I do

```
$#{$graph{$root}{"children"}
```

it gets commented out.

Comment: Are you missing a closing `}` ?

Comment: @ mob confirmed.  If you add the closing brace then it behaves as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  When you submit code, it is worth making it into a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example.  Roughly like the code in my answer, in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below works for me, giving the output:

```
$ perl x.pl
List: apple banana orange
Size: 2
$
```

Code — note the properly closed sets of braces (the code in the question has issues that prevent it compiling):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

my $root = "root";

$OFS = " ";
my %graph;
@{$graph{$root}{"children"}} = ('apple', 'banana', 'orange');

print  "List:", @{$graph{$root}{"children"}}, "\n";
printf "Size: %d\n", $#{$graph{$root}{"children"}};
```

(Perl 5.12.1 on RHEL 5 for x86/64)

Comment: Thanks, I was also confused because gedit comments out after the #, even though in this case it is not a comment.

Comment: Perl is horribly difficult for an editor to parse.  Consider: `$x =~ s#x#y/z#;` — no comment, but...